# Mean Square Error not decreasing during gradient descent

Tags: gradient-descent, mlp, ann

I am currently writing a program which is supposed to implement gradient descent to train a prediction model. I am encountering an error whereby my MSE continuously increases, and the network never trains.

````
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

##Import and Remove Labels##
data=pd.read_excel("C:/Users/motal/Documents/Zaheer/Data bez.xls",sheet_name=1)
data=np.array(data)
data= data[2:-1,2:]


###Shuffle and Split##
np.random.shuffle(data.T)
Dm,Dn= data.shape
train_pers= int(0.8*Dn)
print("# of parameters=",Dm)
print("# of samples=",Dn)

Train = data[0:Dm, 0:train_pers]
Test = data[0:Dm, train_pers:Dn]
I_train = Train[0:-1, :]
Y_train = Train[-1:, :]
I_test = Test[0:-1, :]
Y_test = Test[-1:, :]

##Scale between 0 and 1
scaler=MinMaxScaler()
I_train=scaler.fit_transform(I_train.T)
I_train=I_train.T
I_test=scaler.fit_transform(I_test.T)
I_test=I_test.T

Im,In=I_train.shape

# print("Number of parameters=",Im)
# print("Number of Samples=",In)


Im,In=I_train.shape
Ym,Yn=Y_train.shape

print(Ym)
print(Yn)

##Network Architecture##
hiddenneutrons=15
outputneurons=1

#Initial Weights and Bias-Hidden Layer
Wh=np.around(np.random.randn(hiddenneutrons,Im),2)
Bh=np.around(np.random.randn(hiddenneutrons,1),2)

print("hidden weights=",Wh)
print("hidden bias=",Bh)

#Initial Weights and Bias-Output Layer
Wo=np.around(np.random.randn(outputneurons,hiddenneutrons),2)
Bo=np.around(np.random.randn(outputneurons,1),2)


print("output weights=",Wo)
print("output bias=",Bo)

def sig(Z):
    return (math.e**Z)/(1+math.e**Z)

def sigderiv(K):
    return ((math.e**K)/(1+math.e**K))*(1-((math.e**K)/(1+math.e**K)))


def relu(Z):
    return np.maximum(0,Z)
def reluderiv(K):
    return K>0

def forwardpass(I,Wh,Bh,Wo,Bo):
    zh=np.dot(Wh,I)+Bh  #unactivated hidden output
    gh=sig(zh)      #activated hidden output
    zo=np.dot(Wo,gh)+Bo #unactivated output output
    go=zo               #activated output output
    return zh,gh,zo,go

zh,gh,zo,go=forwardpass(I_train,Wh,Bh,Wo,Bo)
print("hidden layer output=",zh)
print("output layer output=",go)

def backwardpass(go,Y,gh,Wo,zh,I):
    MSE=np.mean((Y-go)*(Y-go))
    dBo=2*np.mean(Y-go)
    dWo=2*np.mean(Y-go)*np.mean(gh,axis=1,keepdims=1)
    dBh=2*np.mean(Y-go)*Wo*np.mean(sigderiv(zh),axis=1,keepdims=1).T
    dWh=2*np.mean(Y-go)*(Wo*np.mean(sigderiv(zh),axis=1,keepdims=1).T).T*np.mean(I,axis=1,keepdims=1).T
    return MSE,dBo, dWo, dBh,dWh


def updateparams(Bo,Wo,Bh,Wh,dBo,dWo,dBh,dWh, alpha):
    Bo=Bo-alpha*dBo
    Wo=Wo-alpha*dWo.T
    Bh=Bh-alpha*dBh.T
    Wh=Wh-alpha*dWh
    return Bo,Wo,Bh,Wh

c=[]
epochs=[]
def gradientDescent(Wh,Bh,Wo,Bo,I,Y,iterations,alpha):
    for i in range(iterations):
        zh, gh, zo, go = forwardpass(I, Wh, Bh, Wo, Bo)
        MSE, dBo, dWo, dBh, dWh = backwardpass(go, Y, gh, Wo, zh, I)
        Bo, Wo, Bh, Wh = updateparams(Bo, Wo, Bh, Wh,dBo,dWo,dBh,dWh, alpha)
        if i % 100==0:
            print("iteration=",i)
            print("MSE=",MSE)
            c.append(MSE)
            epochs.append(i)
    return Wh,Bh,Wo,Bo

Wh,Bh,Wo,Bo= gradientDescent(Wh,Bh,Wo,Bo,I_train,Y_train,1000000,.000000000001)

zh,gh,zo,go=forwardpass(I_test,Wh,Bh,Wo,Bo,)

linreg=LinearRegression()
Y_test=Y_test.reshape(-1,1)
go=go.reshape(-1,1)
linreg.fit(Y_test,go)
trendline= linreg.predict(Y_test)

r_squared=round(r2_score(go,trendline),3)
print(r_squared)

fig1, ax1=plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2=plt.subplots()

ax1.plot(epochs,c)
ax1.set_title("Training")
ax1.set_xlabel("Epochs")
ax1.set_ylabel("MSE")
ax2.scatter(Y_test,go)
ax2.plot(Y_test,trendline,label="R_squared",color= "r")
ax2.set_title("Predicted vs Test")
ax2.set_xlabel("Test")
ax2.set_ylabel("Predicted")
ax2.text(.8,.7,r_squared,transform=ax2.transAxes)
ax2.legend()
ax2.grid()
ax2.set_xlim([0, 3.5])
# ax2.set_ylim([0, 5])
plt.show()```
````